# Parse a .net datetime string into a NSDate object in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a string that contains a .net datetime (rawData) and I am trying to parse it into a `NSDate` object using a `NSDateFormatter`. I think my format string might be wrong or something because the `dateFromString:` method is returning nil. Can any one please help me figure out the issue here?

```
NSString *rawData = @"2009-10-20T06:01:00-07:00";
//Strip the colon out of the time zone
NSRange timezone = NSMakeRange([data length] - 3, 3);
NSString *cleanData = [rawData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:timezone ];

//Setup a formatter and parse it into a NSDate object
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *result = [df dateFromString: cleanData]; //Result is nil
```

Comment: Apple OS use the following information to format date: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns  which say hours in 24-hour format is HH.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a date string into an NSDate object in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999396/how-to-parse-a-date-string-into-an-nsdate-object-in-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this code and it's work:

```
NSString *rawData = @"2009-10-20 06:01:00-07:00";
//Strip the colon out of the time zone
NSRange timezone = NSMakeRange([rawData length] - 3, 3);
NSString *cleanData = [rawData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:timezone ];
// Get rid of the T also
cleanData = [cleanData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];

//Setup a formatter and parse it into a NSDate object
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
NSDate *result = [df dateFromString: cleanData]; //Result is ni
NSLog(@"Result %@", result);
```

Couple of notes

1. Get rid of the T.
2. 24-Hour format for hours is HH

Comment: Did you test it on the device as well? From my experience trying to parse dates into strings using NSDateFormatter without specifying a locale or time and date styles will sometimes work on the simulator but not on the device.

Comment: I don't have my cable with me at the moment.  I will test when I reach home and let you know.

Comment: I have tested this in the simulator and its working good. Thank you all very much for the help. I will test this on the device tomorrow and post my results.

Answer (score 3):

With iOS 6.0 and higher, representation for timezone with colon separating hour and minutes is added.(`ZZZZZ` or fallback `z`)Refer the following link [Date Formats](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

This makes the code very simple

```
NSString *dateString = @"2009-10-20T06:01:00-07:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS";
    df.locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"] autorelease];
    NSDate *result = [df dateFromString:rawData];
```

Comment: I was not able to get this one to work, I think the formatting string is causing an issue here. Thanks for the reply tho.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like .NET outputs dates as ISO 8601 strings? For parsing these I use an open source NSFormatter subclass written by Peter Hosey, which you can find [here](http://boredzo.org/iso8601unparser/). Unfortunately it's not trivial to parse these correctly using a simple dateFormat string. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201216/is-there-a-simple-way-of-converting-an-iso8601-timestamp-to-a-formatted-nsdate).

Comment: Thanks for the links. These solutions also worked nicely as well. The ISO8601DateFormatter makes for some clean code.