# restkit and iso date

Tags: date, restkit, isodate

I'm having trouble parsing an iso date from my json api/mongodb using rest kit.

The iso date string I'm getting back is "2011-11-15T04:00:00Z" whichdoesn't get converted to an nsdate in my object, showing as null.

What's the recommended work around if I can't format my date string, server side at the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saw this post in google groups

http://groups.google.com/group/restkit/browse_thread/thread/5ffaa4626209881

Looks like you would have to create your own date formatter and add it to the object mapper

Comment: Also check out this answer to a similar post. It looks you can also find a link to an ISO8601 parser there, which is good since the link in the google groups post is now broken. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3201886/654870