# Convert an ISO6801 date to NSDate for RestKit object mapping

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, restkit

This problem appears to be affecting a lot of objective-c developers working with custom built restful APIS -- like [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/restkit/Bf-qRiYgmIE/x8Lz249mSOQJ) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811607/restkit-and-iso-date). On the backend we are using ISO 6801 dates, and I've had trouble getting a valid date when I pull objects down from the server. This is the date format we use, but NSDate can't recognize it because the colon in the time zone offset:

`1981-09-01T00:00:00-06:00`

I've tried using this [ISO6801 parser and unparser](http://boredzo.org/iso8601unparser/), which is included in the latest version of RestKit, but I can't figure out how to successfully add it to the object mapping. How do I add a date formatter to a RestKit objectmapping? Can anyone provide a code sample of how to do this?

Here is my failed code. This is what I'm looking for and tried based on a [google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/restkit/Bf-qRiYgmIE/hDCXVt9DflYJ), but it gives errors:

```
[mapping.dateFormatStrings addObject:[[MyISO8601DateFormatter] alloc] init]];
```

There's a [related answer on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3201886/654870), but it is partly outdated and lacks a working example.

Comment: To use non-ARC code in an ARC project, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project). In fact, RestKit itself is not ARC compliant.

Comment: Thanks. Got that working just fine, still have the same problems of adding the date formatter to the RestKit object mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a date formatter you do this:

```
[RKObjectMapping addDefaultDateFormatter: formatter];
```

If that flavor doesn't suit you, you can try some of the other options you will see there in the header file.

Comment: Thanks -- that will do it globally. I was wondering how to add it to a particular mapping, but I just figured that part out too. You have throw the date formatter into an array as in: mapping.dateFormatters = [NSArray arrayWithObject: isoDateFormatter];.