# Objective C - how to get current time in ISO 8601 format?

Tags: objective-c, date

How would I get the current time in ISO 8601 format? It should look something like 2011-11-16T22:06Z

Comment: Can't you use a simple NSDateFormatter call for that -- "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ" or some such?  (Don't forget to set Locale to avoid the AM/PM mess.)

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks I did just that and it worked! do you want to convert it to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a simple NSDateFormatter call for that -- "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ" or some such. (Don't forget to set Locale to avoid the AM/PM mess.)

Comment: I believe it should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'`

Comment: In my case yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z' doesn't work for ISO 8601 if date is 2013-11-29T12:42+06.00. yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mmZ works fine

Comment: @user1264176 - I've never seen a timezone with a dot in it like that.  For a timezone with a colon you use ZZZZZ.  For no colon Z works fine.

Comment: What I meant is that I had to remove ' (apostrophe) which wraps Z.

Comment: And yeah, sorry, the timezone is actually with colon. I've made a typo.

Comment: @user1264176 - The format listed by the OP included a literal "Z" (for Zulu/GMT), so Bot's comment was correct.  So far as I know the formatter will not read/write that symbol, so it must be literally coded (with Z in single quotes), and the timezone of the formatter must be explicitly set to GMT.

Comment: @HotLicks I have two servers lets say dev and prod and iOS app that runs on iOS7. Dev gives me 2013-11-29T12:42Z and prod 2013-11-29T12:42+06:00. In case yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z' format I can work fine with dev server but if I receive prod's date NSDateFormatter returns me nil. In case yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ format my app works fine with both dev and prod.

Comment: @user1264176 - Yeah, I've never tried reading a "Z" with a "Z" specifier, so I can't say whether it works or not.  (The documentation is not particularly helpful on this point.)  In some cases it is necessary to examine the received date's structure first and either select from several or massage the format into something the formatter can handle.

Answer (score 5):

A pure C solution, using only standard C features:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(void) {
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *now_tm = gmtime(&now);
    char iso_8601[] = "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MMZ"; 
    /* init just to get the right length */

    strftime(iso_8601, sizeof iso_8601, "%FT%RZ", now_tm);
    puts(iso_8601);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found your answer by [looking at this potentially duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201216/is-there-a-simple-way-of-converting-an-iso8601-timestamp-to-a-formatted-nsdate) and one of the answers says to use a open source solution called Peter Hosey's ISO8601DateFormatter.

Which you can [download from here](http://boredzo.org/iso8601unparser/).  Bonus, it was updated only a few days ago (5-November-2011).

And, to get the current date & time... you'd do:

```
ISO8601DateFormatter *formatter = [[ISO8601DateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[formatter release];
formatter = nil;
```

Comment: I am looking for a simple solution without the use of any libraries.

Comment: This is the right answer, a single file is no library!  And its an amazingly good piece of code too...