# ISO8601 datetime generate (Like Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z)

Tags: objective-c

How can I generate (iOS 7) `ISO 8601` datetimes like `Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z` in PHP?

---

PHP Code:

```
gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z'); // Output: 2014-02-12T12:08:43Z
```

Objective-C: (Looking around the web I found this code, but its not returning exactly ISO 8601)

```
- (NSString *)timestampISO8601 // Output: 2014-02-12T10:12:19-02:00
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

Comment: Have you looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161615/objective-c-how-to-get-current-time-in-iso-8601-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
```

Is what I use and it works.