# Parsing ISO 8601 with NSDateFormatter

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, iso8601

I've read through the various posts on SO about this, but have still not solved the problem.

Here's the string that I'm trying to parse into an `NSDate` object:

```
2012-04-08T12:00:00.00+02:00
```

I understand that the problem is the time zone format. Here's the date format string that I'm trying:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SSZZZZ
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This looks a lot like:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201216/is-there-a-simple-way-of-converting-an-iso8601-timestamp-to-a-formatted-nsdate

which has three answers.

Comment: I think that thread doesn't address this issue -- there's another thread somewhere that does.  And the gist of the answer is that you must somehow remove that last ":" character before attempting to parse the date with NSDateFormatter.

Comment: I've seen that question. It doesn't answer my question. Answer 1 doesn't even answer the question, answer 2 doesn't use `NSDateFormatter`, and answer 3 uses methods that don't exist on iOS.

Comment: For those who don't know how to do this `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ`

Comment: For the string `2013-09-01T14:23:12.2177735+00:00` the following formatter worked for me: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things:

- Use the -[NSDateFormatter getObjectValue:forString:range:error:] method to learn how much of the string was parsed and what error prevented parsing further.
- The ZZZZ format string corresponds to something like "GMT+02:00", with that "GMT" in there.  You may need to inject that into the string you're parsing for it to work.
- Apple's Data Formatting Guide advises ["Consider Unix Functions for Fixed-Format, Unlocalized Dates"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW12).

Comment: Thanks! Injecting the "GMT" did the trick. I'll also note that a helpful tip is to log out what `NSDateFormatter` expects a date using your format to look like, like this: `[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Now the dedicated NSISO8601DateFormatter is available.