# How to convert NSString to NSDate with this format : "2012-08-01T12:43:35+02:00"?

Tags: objective-c, ios, date

I need to convert NSString like this : "2012-08-01T12:43:35+02:00" to NSDate, but i don't find the good format...

I use this category code to convert NSString to NSDate :

```
[NSDate dateFromString:@"2012-08-01T12:43:35+02:00" withFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
```

```
+ (NSDate*) dateFromString:(NSString*)dateString withFormat:(NSString*)format 
{
    return [self dateFromString:dateString withFormat:format andLocaleIdentifier:@"fr"];
}

+ (NSDate*) dateFromString:(NSString*)dateString withFormat:(NSString*)format andLocaleIdentifier:(NSString*)localeIdentifier
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:format];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:localeIdentifier];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
    [locale release];

    NSDate *returnDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    [dateFormatter release];

    return returnDate;
}
```

I tried all the format i can, but no one is correct...

**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss** >> 2012-08-04T18:05:14
**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssv** >> 2012-08-04T18:05:14France Time
**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssvv** >> 2012-08-04T18:05:14GMT+02:00
**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssvvv** >> 2012-08-04T18:05:14GMT+02:00
**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssV** >> 2012-08-04T18:05:14CEST
**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssVV** >> 2012-08-04T18:05:14GMT+02:00
**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssVVV** >> 2012-08-04T18:05:14GMT+02:00
**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssVVVV** >> 2012-08-04T18:05:14France Time
**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz** >> 2012-08-04T18:05:14GMT+02:00
**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszz** >> 2012-08-04T18:05:14GMT+02:00
**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz** >> 2012-08-04T18:05:14GMT+02:00
**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzzz** >> 2012-08-04T18:05:14Central European Summer Time
**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ** >> 2012-08-04T18:05:14+0200
**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ** >> 2012-08-04T18:05:14+0200
**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ** >> 2012-08-04T18:05:14+0200
**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ** >> 2012-08-04T18:05:14GMT+02:00

How can i do ?

---

## [Edit] First ugly solution :

1. Delete the last colon with a regex
2. Convert the string with this format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"

There is the regex

```
    NSString* dateString = @"2012-08-01T12:43:35+02:00";
    NSMutableString* dateWithoutColonString = [dateString mutableCopy];

    NSRegularExpression* lastColonRegex = [NSRegularExpression
                                           regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([\\+\\-][0-9][0-9]):"
                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                           error:nil];

    [lastColonRegex replaceMatchesInString:dateWithoutColonString
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                range:NSMakeRange(0, [dateString  length])
                         withTemplate:@"$1"];
```

Comment: If you find any solution for the problem please let me know

Comment: See also: [Parsing ISO 8601 with NSDateFormatter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10057456)

Answer (score 1):

use   [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a discussion of [parsing Internet-style dates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1480.html) which is similar to your code but has a couple changes. It always uses the `en_US_POSIX` locale, and it uses `[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]` instead of your local timezone for parsing. Try that and see if the results work better for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but if I'm not mistaken, it don't solved my problem...

Comment: It don't recognize the format and return nil.