# NSDate and the Device's Timezone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to parse a date like this: `2012-10-20T13:45:00+002` with this code:

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2012-10-20T13:45:00+002"];
```

But when I try to output it on a device that its timezone is already +2 using this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
dateformatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ar_EG"];
cell.infoLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

The output is: 15:43 instead of 13:45 as it should be.
Any help would be appreciated.
PS: I'm running iOS5/6, Xcode 4.5 on iPhone and I tried on both simulator and a physical device.

Comment: The ZZZ field is expressed in minutes, not hours.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! This is exactly why! I was also wondering why it displays the date 2 minutes earlier.
Can you please tell me what is the correct symbol? I tried reading in http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns but I am unsure.

Comment: I believe you will need to append a pair of zeros to the end of the timestamp, to get it to parse correctly.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't seem to work: 
Original string:  2012-11-25T16:00:00+002
After adding the zeros:  2012-11-25T16:00:00+00200
NSLog of the NSDate object:     2012-11-25 15:58:00 +0000

Comment: It may be that the formatter can't handle the extra leading zero.  (But are you sure you're passing the *modified* string to the formatter, and not the original?)

Comment: (Keep in mind that NSStrings are invariant.  When you do, eg, `stringByAppendingString` the original strings are not modified -- you must capture and use the resulting string.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add locale and timezone

> [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];  // Locale that you want
>   [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];  // Timezone the same

Comment: Thank you a lot, but nothing changed, any other thoughts?

Comment: Can you try using this YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ with y in upper case.

Comment: A very ugly soultion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810159/how-to-convert-nsstring-to-nsdate-with-this-format-2012-08-01t1243350200