# Making an NSDateFormatter to parse ISO dates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a simple question but it is driving me nuts. I am using an API, and I get a JSon object back, and one of the fields is a date. The date is formatted like this: 2013-05-17T02:00:00.000Z. I cannot seem to get the NSDateformatter correct for this date. Would anyone be willing to give me a hand?

If it is not clear, I am using objective c for an iPhone app. My goal is to get a NSDate object at the end of this. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057456/parsing-iso-8601-with-nsdateformatter

Comment: @TBlue a simple downvote would suffice, instead of the yada-yada :-)

Answer (score 2):

That's one of the ISO 8601 formats. Parsing it with NSDateFormatter can be tricky at best, which is why I wrote [an NSFormatter subclass specifically for parsing and unparsing any ISO 8601 format](https://github.com/boredzo/iso-8601-date-formatter).

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to get the correct format for that string. 
Then you should be able to do something like:

```
NSString * dateString = jsonDict[@"dateKey"];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"]
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:dateString];
```

The T is in there to separate date from time and the Z specifies Zulu time. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8405125/1074558)

Comment: Don't forget the single-quotes to identify the T and Z as literal characters rather than special formatting characters.

Comment: And the year should be `yyyy`, not `hhhh`.

Comment: And since it's Zulu time the timezone should be set to UTC.