# Having trouble converting this NSString to NSDate

Tags: ios, nsdate, iso8601

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a simple way of converting an ISO8601 timestamp to a formatted NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201216/is-there-a-simple-way-of-converting-an-iso8601-timestamp-to-a-formatted-nsdate)

I can't convert this NSString to an NSDate:    `2010-03-06T10:06:00-05:00`

To be honest, I can not decipher the Unicode docs, where they talk about generic wall time , standard/daylight time, offsets from GMT as a fallback, etc.

To show that I have made a decent effort, here is what I have as the dateformatter:  `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ:ZZ"`

If I strip out the timezone such that the date becomes `2010-03-06T10:06:00` then I know what to do.  But how many letter "Z"s do I need, and are they upper case? Should I be removing the colon from the -05:00 ? The timezone has been my achilles heel with these conversions.

Could someone please help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201216/is-there-a-simple-way-of-converting-an-iso8601-timestamp-to-a-formatted-nsdate?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201216/is-there-a-simple-way-of-converting-an-iso8601-timestamp-to-a-formatted-nsdate?rq=1

seems to be the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [ISO 8601 date formatter](http://boredzo.org/iso8601unparser/) and see if that works for you.