# Using methods from non-ARC libraries in an ARC project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

I am using the excellent, however, non-ARC project: https://github.com/boredzo/iso-8601-date-formatter

I am trying to use the following method from this library which is non-ARC in an ARC project:

```
- (NSDate *) dateFromString:(NSString *)string timeZone:(out NSTimeZone **)outTimeZone;
```

I have tried:

```
group.updatedAt = [formatter dateFromString:someString timeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
group.updatedAt = [formatter dateFromString:someString timeZone:*__autorelease [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
group.updatedAt = [formatter dateFromString:someString timeZone:(*__autoreleasing [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]] *);
group.updatedAt = [formatter dateFromString:someString timeZone:[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] autorelease]];
```

Note that I am fairly new to iOS, so I don't have any experience with memory management.

But with all these attempts, I received the following error message:

```
Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'NSTimeZone *__autoreleasing *' is disallowed with ARC
```

**So how do I use a non-ARC library's methods in an ARC Project?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NSTimeZone` is an output parameter, so you need to pass a pointer to a pointer, like this:

```
NSTimeZone *theTimeZone = nil;
group.updatedAt = [formatter dateFromString:someString timeZone:&theTimeZone];
```

When the function returns, `theTimeZone` will be set to the output value of the function.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight See my update to the question, does the variable have to be set to nil or can it be set to [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]

Comment: just read your question over once more, so basically, it just needs any timeZone variable, and the function does what it wants with it? How do I get the function to output the local time zone? @dasblinkenlight

Comment: Actually I didn't realize exactly what this function does, it just sets it to a UTC timezone and then tells you what timezone it originally was from, right?

Comment: @GangstaGraham: `dateFromString:timeZone:` doesn't set anything; it parses the string, which should have a time zone in it, and returns both the date (directly) and the time zone (via the pointer). So a string that gives the time zone as “Z” will get you the UTC time zone, whereas a string containing an offset (such as “-0800”) will get you a time zone with that offset.