# How to convert ISO-8601 Duration to NSDate....?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter, iso8601

I have a string which contains a duration ISO-8601 format. I need to convert this to NSDate.

I have looked at a couple of categories but could not find a suitable option.

Any help is appreciated.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#duration

Comment: What to you mean converting a duration with a date? Don't you want to try converting a duration into a future ending date according to a starting date?

Comment: NSDate isn't used to represent duration.  NSTimeInterval is used for that.  And, to my knowledge, there is no standard tool to do conversion between ISO-8601 durations and NSTimeInterval, so you will have to roll your own.  It couldn't be that hard, other than deciding how long a month is.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201216/is-there-a-simple-way-of-converting-an-iso8601-timestamp-to-a-formatted-nsdate, maybe help you.